# How to show custom description for each test in pytest html report

Tags: python, pytest, pytest-html

I am looking for a solution to include custom description for each test (I have about 15-20 tests in a test.py file). I want to show the description for each test in pytest html report. Something like "Login test" for test1, "User name input" for test2 etc.
I have a conftest.py in the folder where the .py tests are present.

```
import pytest
from py.xml import html
@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_header(cells):
    cells.insert(2, html.th('Custom Description'))

@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_row(report, cells):
    custom_description = getattr(report, "custom_description", "")
    cells.insert(2, html.td(custom_description))

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def custom_description(request):
    return request.function.__doc__
```

My test function looks like this.
def test_001(custom_description, request):
print('This is test 1')
assert True
request.node.report_custom_description = "This is a login test"

```
def test_002(custom_description, request):
    print('This is test 2')
    assert True
    request.node.report_custom_description = "This is user name test"
```

The html report is showing the extra column (Custom Description) I added, but its not showing anything under that column. Its just empty.
I tried removing the empty quote in custom_description = getattr(report, "custom_description", "") but that throws error.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to set this description in dynamically in a test?

Please have a look at the solution based on your code that uses test docstring as a custom description:

```
import pytest
from py.xml import html

@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_header(cells):
    cells.insert(2, html.th('Custom Description'))

@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_row(report, cells):
    custom_description = getattr(report, "custom_description", "")
    cells.insert(2, html.td(custom_description))

@pytest.hookimpl(hookwrapper=True)
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    outcome._result.custom_description = item.function.__doc__
```

Here I implement hook wrapper for hook [pytest_runtest_makereport](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#pytest.hookspec.pytest_runtest_makereport).

As stated in docs, it returns `TestReport` instance, so you can use a hook wrapper (generator function) that yields this instance. Then you just modify it with an `item.function.__doc__` property.

Also your tests will be simpler:

```
def test_001():
    """This is a login test"""
    print('This is test 1')
    assert True

def test_002():
    """This is user name test"""
    print('This is test 2')
    assert True
```

Report:
[image: Report]

Comment: Perfect, works great and thank you for this solution. Also how do I suppress the below warning when I run pytest? PytestDeprecationWarning: The hookimpl pytest_html_results_table_row uses old-style configuration options (marks or attributes).
  Please use the pytest.hookimpl(optionalhook=True) decorator instead
   to configure the hooks.

Comment: it works, thank you. Not sure why people not clicking up button

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution to that warning. I had to decorate with `@pytest.hookimpl(optionalhook=True)` in both `def pytest_html_results_table_header(cells)` and `def pytest_html_results_table_row(report, cells)`